# How to dynamically add routes to a lazyloaded Module?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular15, angular-lazyloading

The route configuration of a lazy-loaded module is structured differently because lazy-loaded modules have their own separate route configurations. In my case, I have routes fetched from the database and need to apply them to the router.config when the user successfully logs in.

the core module is lazyloaded in the app module on path 'core'.

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'core', loadChildren: () => import('@modules/pu-core/pu-core.module').then(m => m.PuCoreModule) }
];
```

**Core module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'layout', component: LayoutComponent, childre:[] },
];
```

on the success of login, the auth service has an observable `apiRoutes$` that holds the routes that needs to be applied to the `layout` path children.

Using of `this.router.config` to dynamically add the children doesn't work since the config is different.

The below implementation doesn't work:

```
constructor(public router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, @SkipSelf() private auth: AuthService) {

    this.auth.routes$.subscribe(
      (routesData: any) => {
        this.router.config[2].children = routesData;
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

- Updating Routes After Login:
  After successful login, you can inject PuCoreRoutingService into your authentication service (or wherever you are handling login success) and update the routes as needed.

```
constructor(private puCoreRoutingService: PuCoreRoutingService) {}

onLoginSuccess(): void {
  this.auth.routes$.subscribe((routesData: Routes) => {
    this.puCoreRoutingService.updateLayoutChildrenRoutes(routesData);
  });
}
```

- Route Update Service in Core Module:
  Create a service within the PuCoreModule that allows updating routes. This service can have a method to update the child routes of the LayoutComponent.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PuCoreRoutingService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public updateLayoutChildrenRoutes(routes: Routes): void {
    const config = this.router.config;
    const layoutRoute = config.find(r => r.path === 'layout');
    if (layoutRoute) {
      layoutRoute.children = routes;
      this.router.resetConfig(config);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for modules that are not lazyloaded. I could have asked chatGPT